# What's going on when a thread blocks in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

When I use two threads `t1` and `t2` to crawl something from the Internet, and write some filtered data into a single file, I use a Lock() instance to guarantee that there's only one thread that is writing to the file. What I know is when `t1.aquire()` is called, `t2.aquire()`will put `t2` into blocking state.
What I wanna know is, what's going on in the Python interpreter with thread `t2` now. Will the interpreter check the state of the thread for every period of time? And further, is the interpreter controlling the CPU time assigned to a single thread or is the host OS?

Comment: A bit offtop, but still explains a lot about treads in python http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to interrupt the acquire() method on a lock by any system call.

acquire()

**Acquire a lock, blocking or non-blocking.**

When acquire invoked without arguments(consider t1): if this thread already owns the lock, increment the **recursion level by one**, and return immediately. 
Otherwise, if another thread owns the lock, block until the lock is unlocked. 
Once the lock is unlocked (not owned by any thread), **then grab ownership**, set the recursion level to one, and return. 
If more than one thread is blocked waiting until the lock is unlocked, only one at a time will be able to grab ownership of the lock. There is no return value in this case.

Comment: Thanks but I actually know things that you mentioned, and I guess that you're talking about `RLock()`. What I want to figure out is **what's happening under the scene when a very thread blocks**, I mean is there something like an event loop to periodically check the blocking state of the threads?

Answer (score 0):

This answer to this question is implementation-specific(that is, depends on the interpreter and OS). In CPython, each Python thread is mapped directly to an OS thread, so scheduling is controlled by an OS. Locking/unlocking is also handled by OS, not the interpreter. In Jython, everything runs under the JVM, which also maps threads directly to native threads. So I don't know any implementation where the Python interpreter handles scheduling and locking by itself.

Comment: thanks a lot! And do you get all these information by reading the source code or somebody's blog?

Comment: @DragonWarrior Reading documentation and books is the best way to learn, in my opinion. I don't think that source code or blogs can be used a consistent source of knowledge.